# iOS phonegap zxing QR scanner plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, barcode-scanner, zxing

I'm looking for a lib to use that comes with zxing QR scanning capabilities for iOS. What's the best option out there right now?

Answer (score 1):

The question is slightly confusing - zxing *is* a QR scanning library. If you mean you are looking for an iOS port of zxing then try the Google one:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list

I know it looks like they're all for Android, but if you download the ZXing-1.7.zip it includes the code for multiple platforms including iOS (although the code base was a bit of a mess last time I checked).

EDIT: Sorry, didn't see the part about PhoneGap (should probably mention that in the question, not just the title). I don't know of an existing PhoneGap plugin, but you can probably write one yourself easily enough if you can get the iOS ZXing examples working.

Answer (score 1):

There is an iPhone Barcode Scanner plugin for Phonegap in the phonegap-plugins github repository [here](http://Barcode%20Scanner%20plugin%20for%20Phonegap). According to the readme, it uses zxing.